# JDBC Datasource returning NULL

Tags: java, spring

I have this working java code that serve as the "datasource":

```
public final class PMF {
        static Driver driver = null;
    static String url = "jdbc:jiql://local";

    static Properties props = new Properties();

    static {
       String password = "jiql";
       String user = "admin";
       props.put("user",user);
       props.put("password",password);
       try {
           Class clazz = Class.forName("org.jiql.jdbc.Driver");
           driver = (Driver) clazz.newInstance();
       } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public static Connection get() {
        try{
            return driver.connect(url,props);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I tried to adapt this code for Spring with the code below:

**jdbc.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.jiql.jdbc.Driver

# development
jdbc.url=jdbc:jiql://local
jdbc.username=admin
jdbc.password=jiql
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- placeholders -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<!-- data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

The "datasource" gets null when I do this in the DAO:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

What could be causing the datasource to be null?

Comment: This maybe obvious but you do have the correct DataSource imported right?

Comment: Are you doing a component scan? Is the DAO being instantiated by spring?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I have this in the spring context:  <context:annotation-config /> <context:component-scan base-package="com.appcloem.server" />

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your DAO class? Does it have the `@Component` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a DAO issue and not JDBC issue. I re-created the app using Spring STS and everything went working.